# PoolingClientConnectionManager Performance Issue

Tags: java, performance, httpclient, instance, connection-pooling

I have the following code which use a `PoolingClientConnectionManager`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int NoOfSimultaneousRequest = 1000;
    int poolsize =1000;

    try{

        if (poolsize>0){

            mgr = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
            mgr.setMaxTotal(poolsize);
            mgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(poolsize);
            httpclient  = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr); 
        }

        Thread [] tr = new Thread[NoOfSimultaneousRequest];
        for(int i=0;i<NoOfSimultaneousRequest;i++){
            MultipleThreadsTest multiTest = new MultipleThreadsTest();

            Thread t = new Thread(multiTest);
            tr[i] = new Thread(multiTest);
        }       

        for(int i=0;i<NoOfSimultaneousRequest;i++){
            tr[i].start();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<NoOfSimultaneousRequest;i++){
            tr[i].join();
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{

        if (mgr!=null){
            mgr.shutdown();
        }

        if (httpclient!=null){
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}


public void run() {
    if (mgr==null){ //if no connection manager then create multiple instances of defaulthttpClient
        HttpClient  hc  = new DefaultHttpClient();                  
        response = invokeWebService(hc,"http://urltoPost") ;

    }else{ //if connection manager is used then use only one instance of httpclient
        response = invokeWebService(httpclient,"http://urltoPost") ;
    }   
}   


private static String invokeWebService(HttpClient httpClient,String url){
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(new URI(url));
    try{
        String response  = httpClient.execute(httpPost,new BasicResponseHandler());
        return response;
    }catch(Exception e){

    }finally{
        if (httpPost != null) {
            httpPost.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I turn off pooling (by setting `poolSize` <= 0) the code performs much faster compared to when pooling is on (`poolSize` > 0). The only difference between these two versions is, when using pooling, there is only one instance of `HttpClient` created (as recommended by Apache) and when pooling is off, multiple instances of `HttpClient` are created. The code is supposed to perform better when I use HTTP connection pooling. But that is not happening. Do you see any issue in my usage of connection manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can not make any valid and supported diagnosis based on this. In order to find out why your application runs faster/slower, you need to gather information, for this you will need to do performance testing. Otherwise you will just be shooting out in the dark.

For a start in your case I would start measuring overall system performance during your test, making sure both test cases are using the same kind of workload.

By overall system performance I mean Utilization, Saturation and Errors on CPU and Memory for a start. You need to find out where is your code execution time going and start digging deeper from there.